# Java Android: Execute more blocks of code at the same time

Tags: android, loops, runnable

How can I execute more blocks of code at the same time? I want to do some things in one block of code and at the same time I want to check or update anything with while(true) {...}
I tried with the interface runnable, but when the cycle while starts (infinite loop because i setted while(true) ), the app blocks...do you help me with any ideas? Please, post your code too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

I'm assuming that when you mention *update* in your question you are referring to a *UI update*.

Comment: an example code? I only need to look a thing which is always executed with a while(true) {...}